# MSXML2 - How to search specific nodes and replace its child nodes

Tags: vba, ms-access, msxml2

I have this XML file

[image: Autodesk parts library XML example]

I need to search for the `<deviceset>` element by its name (for example name="DB_") and replace its children subtree `<technologies>` with updated data.

So far I made function that returns `MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement` `<technologies>` with correct structure, but I have no clue how to search and replace in the main document.

I'm trying this approach

```
'Select everything from table Interlink - This table contains element's names
Dim RS As Recordset
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Interlink")

'Create new document and load the file
Dim oDoc As DOMDocument60
Set oDoc = New DOMDocument60
oDoc.async = False
oDoc.Load CurrentProject.Path & "\JLC_pattern.xml"

Dim Tech As IXMLDOMElement      'I can set this to contain updated <technologies> subtree
'is it better to use IXMLDOMNode? or IXMLDOMDocumentFragment?

Dim devSets As IXMLDOMNodeList  'Collection ?
Dim devSet As IXMLDOMNode       'Node?


'Loop through the recordset, search for elements and replace the subtree <technologies>
Do Until RS.EOF
    'Recordset now contains the deviceset name attribute
    Debug.Print RS.Fields("lbrDeviceSetName")  ' first record contains "DB_"
    
    'I can't find the right method to find the node or collection
    'I have tried:
    Set devSets = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("deviceset")   'and
    Set devSets = oDoc.selectNodes("//eagle/drawing/library/devicesets/deviceset")
    'but devSets collection is always empty
    For Each devSet In devSets
        Debug.Print devSet.baseName ' this does not loop
    Next devSet

    'I made a function that returns IXMLDOMNode with needed data structure
    'Once I find the node I need to replace the subtree
    'and move to the next deviceset name
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
'Save the modified XML document to disk
oDoc.Save CurrentProject.Path & "\SynthetizedDoc.xml"
RS.Close

'Cleanup...
```

It may be easier to loop through the collection of nodes and search the recordset instead of looping through the recordset and search the nodes.

Can anyone give me a clue please?

**EDIT:** I have expanded the VBA code with `for each loop`

Pattern XML is here [JLC_Pattern.xml](http://depot.althan.cz/files/jlc_pattern.xml)

**EDIT 2:** The `<technologies>` subtree can be quite huge. I don't want to overwhelm this post by code. I have a function `getTechnology(tech as string) as IXMLDOMElement` that pulls data from DB. Function output content can be downloaded here: [IXMLDOMElement.xml](http://depot.althan.cz/files/technologies.xml) The issue is not this function, I just don't know how to insert this output into the correct place of the `oDoc`

Comment: Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757073(v=vs.85)#jscript-example) of use?

Comment: Have a look at XPath for querying the XML for specific nodes:
- [XPath Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/msxml/use-contains-xpath-function)
- [XPath Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/msxml/use-xpath-against-default-namespace)

Comment: Please include a *sample* of XML in body of post and not as image for a [mcve]. See also [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451).

Comment: If you can share a sample XML file you're more likely to get help.  No-one wants to re-type that based on the image.

Comment: There's a hyperlink to the XML at the bottom of the post

Comment: @Combinatix - missed that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```vb
'Create new document and load the file
Dim oDoc As DOMDocument60
Dim devSet As IXMLDOMNode

Set oDoc = New DOMDocument60
oDoc.async = False

'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762632(v=vs.85)
oDoc.SetProperty "ProhibitDTD", False 'needed for MSXML6

oDoc.validateOnParse = False 'or get a DTD-related error
                             '"The element 'eagle' is used but not declared in the DTD/Schema."

'always test for load errors
If Not oDoc.Load("C:\Tester\JLC_pattern.xml") Then
    Debug.Print oDoc.parseError.reason
    Exit Sub
End If

'select a single node based on its name attribute value
Set devSet = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/eagle/drawing/library/devicesets/deviceset[@name='DB_']")
If Not devSet Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print devSet.XML
    'work with devSet child nodes...
Else
    Debug.Print "node not found"
End If
```

Comment: It indeed works for me as well! I can't believe I forgot to check the parseError.